# how to use repositories in @AfterLoad(), @BeforeUpdate() Typeorm in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

we are using subscriber and listener of typeorm in nestJs and want to use repository in AfterLoad function.

```
    async beforeUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<any>) {
        const entityClassName = event.entity.constructor.name;
    
        const userRepository = await event.manager.getRepository(User);
    
        const result = await repository
          .createQueryBuilder('user')
          .andWhereInIds(event.entity.updatedById)
          .getOne();
        const log = new AuditLog();
  // set field values
          log.before = event.databaseEntity;
          log.after = event.entity;
          log.entity = event.metadata.tableName.toString();
          log.date = new Date();
          log.eventType = EventType.UPDATE;
          log.updatedBy = {
            id: result.id,
            lastName: result.lastName,
            phoneNumber: result.phoneNumber,
          };
  // set field values

          const logRepository = await event.manager.getRepository(AuditLog);
          await logRepository.save(log);
      }
```

but repository.save() does not working. any one can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can use getConnection() and then getEntityManager() but its not a good way to use repository in after load because it will create a circular load of entity and Couse to failed project.
so don't use repository in afterload()